# Adding size information of dataset to file name

Tags: matlab, loops, rename, filenames

I have several datasets, called '51.raw' '52.raw'... until '69.raw' and after I run these datasets in my code the size of these datasets changes from 375x91x223 to sizes with varying y-dimensions (i.e. '51.raw' output: 375x45x223; '52.raw' output: 375x50x223, ... different with each dataset).

I want to later save the '.raw' file name with this information (i.e. '51_375x45x223.raw') and also want to use the new dataset size to later reshape the dataset within my code. I have attempted to do this but need help:

```
for k=51:69

data=reshape(data,[375 91 223]); % from earlier in the code after importing data

% then executes code with dimensions of 'data' chaging to 375x45x223, ...

length=size(data); dimensions.([num2str(k)]) = length; %save size in 'dimensions'.

path=['C:\Example\'];
name= sprintf('%d.raw',k);

write([path name], data);  
% 'write' is a function to save the dat in specified path and name (value of k). I don't know how to add the size of the dataset to the name.
```

Also later I want to reshape the dataset 'data' for this iteration and do a reshape with the new y dimensions value.

```
i.e. data=reshape(data,[375 new y-dimension 223]);
```

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just save the dimensions *inside* your file in a header row? That is far better that trying to use the file name to convey information about it's contents

Comment: Thanks for your comment Suever, the output is saved as a .raw file. Then in order to open it in other softwares (ImageJ) it will be more convenient if others want to do it. Plus what you have mentioned is also what I thought but I was asked to change it to the filename but I'm not sure how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily convert your dimensions to a string which will be saved as a file.

```
% Create a string of the form: dim1xdim2xdim3x...
dims = num2cell(size(data));
dimstr = sprintf('%dx', dims{:});
dimstr = dimstr(1:end-1);

% Append this to your "normal" filename
folder = 'C:\Example\';
filename = fullfile(folder, sprintf('%d_%s.raw', k, dimstr));

write(filename, data);
```

That being said, it is far better include this dimension information *within* the file itself rather than relying on the filename.

As a side note, avoid using names of internal functions as variable names such as `length`, and `path`. This can potentially result in strange and unexpected behavior in the future.

**Update**

If you need to parse the filename, you could use `textscan` to do that:

```
filename = '1_2x3x4.raw';

ndims = sum(filename == 'x') + 1;
fspec = repmat('%dx', [1 ndims]); 
parts = textscan(filename, ['%d_', fspec(1:end-1)]);

% Then load your data

% Now reshape it based on the filename
data = reshape(data, parts{2:end});
```

Comment: Thank you Suever for your help. How would you later recall the new y-dimension (e.g. 49) to 'reshape' from the string? So for the second for loop I have I want it to read the dimensions 'dim1xdim2xdim3' and then reshape: data=reshape(data, [dim1 dim2 dim3])

Comment: @a.kk Added some updated code to read the dimensions back in from the filename

Comment: Thank you Suever! I have tried running this but I get an error with my data and other data that I run: 'Error using reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.'

Comment: Okay, I understand why, my mistake don't worry. Thanks again :)